# asp.net Using a Base href tag is causing my code file to not be found

Tags: c#, asp.net, href

I have an old asp.net webform that is using master pages. About a month ago I placed a base href tag in the master page to help resolve some link issues I was having.

```
<head runat="server">
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

    <title><%: Page.Title %> - JCPS DMC</title>

    <base href="/DMC/" />
    <link href="/DMC/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" />
</head>
```

It helped to resolve the link issues I was having, but I guess it created a new issue I've just been made aware of. If somebody clicks on a link to kick off codebehind logic it goes to a "HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found" page. The code file is located in DMC/CCR/collegeTranscript.aspx.cs, but you can see in the screenshot below that it's looking for the file straight off the root directory DMC/collegeTranscript.aspx.cs

[image]

If I comment out the  line and click on the link it finds the code file with no issues. I've tried modifying the CodeBehind reference in my collegeTranscripts.aspx page in several different ways but it has no affect.

```
<%@ Page Title="College Transcript" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Content.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="collegeTranscript.aspx.cs" Inherits="DMC.CCR.collegeTranscript" %>
```

I've tried changing it to:

/DMC/CCR/collegeTranscript.aspx.cs

/CCR/collegeTranscript.aspx.cs

/collegeTranscript.aspx.cs

I've even tried changing the key word "CodeBehind" to "CodeFile".  Nothing seems to work. I'm hoping there's an easy solution for this that I'm just not aware of?

Just in case this helps, here's the code for the onClick event:

```
<div class="col-2">
    <div class="col big-box text-center">
        <asp:ImageButton id="expPDF" ImageUrl="Images/icons/pdf.png" AlternateText="Export to PDF"
            style="background-color: white; border: none;" OnClick="expPDF_Click" runat="server" />
    </div>
</div>
```

As well as the codebehind page load function:

```
namespace DMC.CCR
{
    public partial class collegeTranscript : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        public int pageID = 94;

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                //Log Site Visit Into
                if (!HttpContext.Current.Request.IsLocal)
                {
                    analytics log = new analytics();
                    log.logActivity(pageID);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly, greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Resolving of URL's with a master page can cause issues, since your child aspx page could be anywhere - maybe even 4 folders deep.

However, I see no reason or rhyme for this:

```
<base href="/DMC/" />
```

Why have above? I would remove above.

Now, let's address the issue of the ".icon" reference.

So, client-side resolution of URL's does not allow use of "~/" to mean root path name. (But code behind, and ANY server control with a runat="server" CAN and will resolve for you!)

So, the simplest solution is to add a runat="server" tag, and now you can resolve using server side "path" code.

So, this should work:

```
<link href="~/Content/BControl.ico" 
      rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" runat="server" />
```

Same goes for your button image. What happens if you nested 2 or 3 folders deep? The path name is relative to your image

So, your button should be this:

```
    <asp:ImageButton id="expPDF" 
     ImageUrl="~/Images/icons/pdf.png" 
     AlternateText="Export to PDF"
     style="background-color: white; border: none;" OnClick="expPDF_Click"
     runat="server" />
```

So once again, note the path name. I assume in above that ImageUrl the folder "Images" is in root. However, say it was in your Content folder.

Once again, if you leave out the "~/", then the path name is relative to the current page - and that we don't want to think about, or care about.

So, that ImageURL might be this:

```
     ImageUrl="~/Content/icons/pdf.png"
```

So, now it doesn’t matter if your aspx page is in some folder, since the path name is from root (~/ = root of site).

> I've tried modifying the Code Behind reference

NO! do NOT mess with that, you will break everything.

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick response and detailed explanations! I used the base href because my directory structures aren't in synch between the production and dev environment. So creating a url that worked in dev was not working in production. To be painfully honest I don't know exactly what I'm doing, so after a lot of Googling the base href was the only thing I could find that would allow the URLs to work in both my dev and production environments.

Comment: I like when someone gives an answer - even if not great, at least you DID think about that href for a reason. As noted, in most cases, if the control in question (such as image control, image button, or a href)? Just add the runat="server", and then you can use the server side "~/" path resolution. That "~/" don't work in markup (non server side) or JavaScript. thus as a result, I'll often use a server side expression in markup or even JavaScript for correct path. So, in your case, just use runat="server", and your path resolving should work for dev or production.